# How do I drag and drop into an NSOutlineView without specifying the row location?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I'm pretty new to Cocoa, and I'm developing an application that does drag/drop from and into `NSOutlineView`.

I've implemented "`outlineView:validateDrop:proposedItem:proposedChildIndex`", and "`outlineView:acceptDrop:item:childIndex:`" methods to make an `NSOutlineView` a destination for dropping. It works all fine, except that it tries to specify a row/location into which the items from a different `NSOutlineView` should be dropped.

My application doesn't really need to specify which row the item should be dropped on or above; ideally, I would like to have the entire `NSOutlineView` box highlighted when I drag-and-drop onto the `NSOutlineView`. Row selection will be done programmatically.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to want to use `NSOutlineView`'s [`setDropItem:dropChildIndex:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/nsoutlineview_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000110-BABIJIFH) to programmatically set the index to insert at.

For highlighting the entire outline view, you may want to try `NSTableView`'s [`setDropRow:dropOperation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000118-SW158) setting the dropRow at -1, which the doc says:

> Passing a value of –1 for row, and NSTableViewDropOn as the operation causes the entire table view to be highlighted rather than a specific row. This is useful if the data displayed by the receiver does not allow the user to drop items at a specific row location.

NSOutlineView inherits from NSTableView, so this might work if the NSOutlineView subclass doesn't screw up the highlighting behavior of NSTableView.

Comment: It looks like for `NSOutlineView`, using:
`setDropItem:nil dropChildIndex:-1` does the trick.
Thanks for your guidance!

Comment: what should be returned after this in `outlineView:validateDrop:proposedItem:proposedChildIndex` after changing the drop location with `setDropItem ` I am trying to find the parent node and when user drags through children I am trying to retarget it to parent item (like finder app). But its not working